# i try to open a unity project and i get an error that i dont know how to solve

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

i tryed opening a Unity project and i got this error

[image: Error i get]

so i opened that file and its a .Json file but everything is written like this:
#çlž %ÕRû??ÏNL q-”"L¿OJohãW‚`BçÕ†xÂ³¹A÷¡9h

i tryed going in visual studio code to try and change the encoding but it doesnt help at all, it translates it into chinese or something. here is the file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NHbw9DGW4bJodRno3fy-bDDunZ72eQvh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The file was broken, delete it and readd packages.

Comment: how do i readd the packages?

Comment: Open the project, probably you'll get some errors, find out what packages are missing, add them again.

Comment: its fixed now thanks for all your help @shingo